# How to properly use Passport.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, passport.js

I am using :

- Node.js
- Express 4.0
- Passport.js
- Google OAuth 2 for Authentication

For each user, I store in a MySQL DB (I don't have the choice regarding this technology) some info from his Google Profile (email etc...), access & refresh tokens, and also additionnal info that the user provides when he registers on my app.

I have seen different uses of passport.js, specifically regarding how that info is stored in session.

1. On [passport.js's configure
   page](http://passportjs.org/guide/configure/), I don't really
   understand the point of the following block of code :

   ```
   passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
     User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
       done(err, user);
     });
   });
   ```

   Basically, each time the user makes a request, or visits a page, there's a request to the DB and information is retrieved. What is the point ? It slows the app a lot. Shouldn't the info from the DB be retrieved when `serializeUser` is called (ie. when the info is stored in session) ?
2. I have read that storing **too much** info in `session` can slow the
   app. What is "too much" ? How much will it slow the app ? Does
   someone know if there are tests somewhere ? My app's pages require a
   different set of data about my user (for example, the homepage will
   only need his name whereas the profile page will need everything,
   another page will need to know what cars he owns etc...). Should I
   store all that info in `session` when `passport.authenticate` checks
   if the user exists in the DB (thus limiting read-requests to the DB
   to approximately one), or only store in session his id and have my
   pages make additionnal requests to the DB when necessary ?
3. Another issue I have : in the registration process, I first have the user log in on his
   Google Account, I store his profile's details *somewhere*, have him
   fill a form for additionnal info, and then I insert everything in
   the DB. The problem is I don't know how to properly store his Google
   Account details until they are inserted into the DB. For the moment,
   I store them in `session`, and then delete that when the insertion
   is successful. More specifically, when no existing user is found in
   my DB, I do, in my `passport.authenticate` callback:

   ```
   return done(null,false,userInfo);
   ```

   Thus, the user is not authenticated and I have 2 issues : I have to
   store that `userInfo` somewhere until the user is registered and I have
   to log him "manually" using `req.login()` after the registration is complete.

   Should I allow him to be authenticated as soon as he logs in on his
   Google Account ? Wouldn't that cause security issues for me if he
   does not complete his registration ?
4. Lastly, I have read about using Reddis. Would that help me with
   these issues ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) serializeUser is filtering the data and storing it in the session cookie.  generally store less in the cookie if you can. You are going to call the db for data about the user anyways so you can just store an ID used to retrieve and reconstruct the user, as seen in deserializeUser.

Request coming in the cookie is provided to the server by the client, the server deserializes the cookie into data, either decrypting cookie content or retrieving user data from the db. Then response headed out the server serializes the client data, scraping off things you wouldn't store in the cookie and putting them in the db, just leaving an id in the cookie.

if you are doing encryption then this can easily be screwed up when you want to scale by running multiple machines who each need to be able to decrypt the data (not really hard, but unnecessary complexity)

Having unencrypted data just lying in the cookie isn't the best, and besides anything in the cookie can add that inkling of extra bandwidth usage for the user.

2) The database calls should be very fast, if they aren't you are going to have a suffering user experience elsewhere anyways. In other words, my strong opinion is that there is an overwhelming argument for staying away from cookies.

consider that cookies are sent with each request; it would be smarter to, instead of shoving data into the session and having it add overhead, have the user data load up temporarily (cached) for a bit after the user makes a request, and then have neither database calls nor overhead from the cookie while the user is actively on your site.

honestly you should be fine at first without caching. Focus on getting your app up with minumum complexity. This way you can modify it according to user feedback faster and have fewer mistakes.

3) When I played with passport I had a similar issue. I would let passport do its job and grant passport-level-verification to the user (so yes they are logged in), then do more data collection separately. If you are concerned about security then make this passport-level verification not fully logged in, and require more data before upgrading to fully logged in.

I could be very off the mark with this one, but that's my recommendation.

4) Redis is good for times when you have multiple node instances and want to store something in memory (say a counter, or that cached user data). This way you don't have variables in the node code holding onto cached data about a user, which another node instance can't take advantage of when the user comes back and the load balancer shoots them to a different instance.
http://www.ourdailycodes.com/2013/09/redis-when-should-i-use-it.html

EDIT:
I should add that session uses a cookie, but only gives the user a unique token the server understands, so that the server can re-gather the user's session data when a connection is received with an accompanying session token. My understanding is that this is the generally correct way for Session to work... but that it varies by implementation (Someone correct me if I am wrong here).

Comment: Thank you very much for your elaborate recommendations ! I 'll try to keep my app simple (as I am still learning Node/Express/Passport) and see if any user complains about poor performance.

Comment: I hope someone does show up with an exact answer for #2 on cookie vs db benchmarking and #3 for proper security with OAuth as well.

Comment: I have also heard that OAuth 1 is a safer bet for developers getting started: http://hueniverse.com/2012/07/26/oauth-2-0-and-the-road-to-hell/

Comment: Yes, I read this post when I started playing with OAuth 2. I'll re-read it carefully when I'm at home, but nevertheless, it's from 2012, so I hope the guys behind OAuth2 have considered his review/suggestions and more to that, Google is (I think) using OAuth2 and planning to drop support for OAuth 1. But thanks for the link :)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on Google planning to drop OAuth 1!

Comment: My pleasure. If someone else ever lands on this topic, [here's Google migration timetable](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#timetable). According to them, OAuth 1.0 has been deprecated since Oct 2013.

Comment: how to use this graphql-passport in Apollo Server **not** in Apollo server express?

I just wanted to ask you that there is an example in Microsoft documentation on how to apply B2C authentication of REACT - NODEJS(expressJS- REST Api). here is the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-react-spa-app and they are using passport library for express but there is nothing on NODEJS(GRAPHQL) Would you please suggest to me how to use that passport library in REACT-NODE JS(GRAPHQL- Apollo Server)?

Answer (score 2):

I used node.js 
This is code from documentation :

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
   done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
   User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
        done(err, user);
   });
});
```

and this is the code, I modified to understand better :

```
var passport = require ('passport')
passport.serializeUser (function(user, done) {
   done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
   var user = _.find(fixtures.users, 'id', id)
       if (user) {
          done (null, user);
       }
       else
          { done (null, false) }
});


module.exports = passport;
```

In serializeUser, client sending cookie with an 'id'. Here '(user)' argument in serializeUser is user profile and client using only 'id' from user profile to send request to server. done callback passing user.id to server.

In deserializedUser, server will look into database and find the user with that 'id' from serializedUser and return the user profile. 
I used 'lodash' to use find and remove methods.

```
var _ = require ('lodash')
var user = _.find(fixtures.users, 'id', id)
```

find will look for user id and return user profile with that id . More details about lodash is here : [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#now) . 
After that I am checking if user exist then return user otherwise return false.

At the end, I am exporting passport.

```
module.exports = passport;
```