# Express + Passport + Session. Executes a query for every page load

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm using Express 4.2.0 with passport 0.2.0.

The express-session middleware that I am using is 1.2.1

I'm relatively new to node authentication so please bear with me.

I noticed that for everyone page load, passport is executing a db request:

```
Executing (default): SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE "users"."user_id"=7 LIMIT 1;
```

This doesn't make sense to me as I would think that the user has already been authenticated and serialized. And the session is now stored in the browser cookie. I also checked that I do have a cookie session stored in my browser.

Here are my app.js configuration:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
//var sys = require('sys');
var cons = require('consolidate');

/* sequelize */
var db = require('./models'); 

/* passport and its friends */
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session');

/* routes */
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');


//filesystem middleware
//var fs = require('fs');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('dust', cons.dust);
app.set('view engine', 'dust');

app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser('hashionhashion'));
app.use(require('less-middleware')(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(session({ secret: 'hashionhashion' })); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session

//routing
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
```

and here is the passport serialize/deserialize function:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.user_id);
});

// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    db.User.find({ where: {user_id: id} }).success(function(user){
        done(null, user);
      }).error(function(err){
        done(err, null);
      });
});
```

Comment: Express-Session does NOT store the Session in the Cookie, only an Identifier of it. The Session itself is stored in memory of the server and then identified by the cookie. 

In my eyes its common practice to only store the user´s Id in the session and not the user itself since you never know if another request altered the user objects state.

Comment: does this mean that it is normal for a db request to be made every single time the user visits a new page?

Comment: Please check [my post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456015/how-to-properly-use-passport-js), and Catalyst's answer. My #1 question is the same as yours. I don't know if "normal" is the term, but it's definitely not unusual.

Comment: I think the #1 Answer makes a good point. I can only add that, in the asynchronous world, making those DB calls is not as big of a deal as it maybe would be with a synchronous framework/language. Its not blocking your process, and the query itself is usualy really fast anyways (and as stated by Catalyst in the other thread - if not you have another problem anyways).

Comment: No it is not normal. Mine was getting executed several time. I moved app.use(express.static('./public')); above passport initialization and not it's reduced to one per page load. I'm still looking for the fix on that one.

Answer (score 1):

Executing a query on each request to fetch the authenticated user data sometimes is not a good practice(but it is commonly used in apps).

In one of my apps, i only needed `id` of the authenticated user rather than all data (like `password`,`last_login_date`,`register_date`, ...) so i changed `passport` configs like below:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, {id: user.id});
});

// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function(object, done) {
    done(null, object);  // object is: {id: user_id}
});
```

and then in your controllers you can get user id from session:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next)=> {
    const userId = req.user.id;
    // now do a database query only if needed :)
});
```

you can also define a custom middleware to fetch user from db and set to 
`req.user` to use in next middleware:

```
function fetchUser (req, res, next) {
    db.User.find({ where: {id:req.user.id} }).success(function(user){
        req.user = user;
        next();  // will trigger next middleware
    }).error(function(err){
        next(err);  // will trigger error handler
    });
}

router.get('/', fetchUser, function(req, res, next)=> {
    const user = req.user;
    // now user is a object that is fetched from db and has all properties
});
```

In this approach you'll execute query for retrieving user from db only if it's needed and not for all routes.